# Can I create a model when my dependent variable is always a yes or a 1?

Tags: pca, predictive-models, binary-data

I have a dataset of tropical cyclone formation locations and geospatial data of environmental conditions (parameters) in the area where each storm formed. Can I use this data to create a model of the most important parameters to estimate when a favorable environment exists? My independent data, the parameters, are variable data (sea surface temperature, relative vorticity, etc.). The dependent variables are the storms, technically they are binary but in my dataset they are all 1's or yeses. In other words I'm just looking at data where a storm did form. PCA was suggested and I have experimented with that to reduce the number of parameters, of which there are 10 in the full dataset, but I don't think I can create a model this way.

So my question is, is there any method that I can use to create a model with the dataset I have? If so what is the method(s)?

Thanks,
Chris

P.S. Just in case you want to ask, it is possible to get data of storms that don't form but the process of identifying non-developing vs. developing disturbances is complex and not something I wish to undertake.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have the response just be "1" -- there's no variation to model. You might consider things like the time between events or the number of events per unit time or various measures of severity (e.g. maximum wind speed or whatever), but the fact that they always occurred given the condition that they occurred is not useful.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was thinking as well but I wanted to check.